# How to get selected checkbox value in edit blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get the selected checkbox value on the edit blade page.

I'm using a query that is used to get student role from users table.

Code in `edit.blade.php`

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Students :</strong>
        <div style="margin-top: 5px" >
        
        <?php

 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'rp') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

             $result = $conn->query("select users.id, users.name from users, model_has_roles where model_has_roles.model_id=users.id and model_has_roles.role_id=14;
           ");
//echo "<select name='name'>";
         echo "<html>";
         echo "<body>";
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $name = $row['name']; 
               echo '<input type=checkbox name="student_id[]" id="student" value="'.$id.'" '.(($ticket->$id == 'student_id' ? 'checked' : '' )).' >'.$name.'';}
     echo "</body>";
     echo "</html>";
?>
```

also trying to use other way `echo 'echo '<input type=checkbox name="student_id[]"  value="'.$id.'" '.( (is_array(old('student_id')) && in_array($id, old('student_id'))) ? ' checked' : '' ).' >'.$name.'';`

But still nothing shown.

I would be very thankful if anyone could point-out mistake I'm doing here.

Comment: This is not Laravel. Laravel doesn't use mysqli.

Comment: Sorry to say but you have to first learn how to make database connections in laravel, and use models, a query builders for accessing table data.
Read about .env file setup https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a laravel question. But you can use conditional after value attribute inside input tag.

Try this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" {{$ticket->$id == 'student_id' ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).